# blob URL as audio src

Tags: javascript, html, audio, blob, src

After I get audio file from input, I make it to url using 'URL.createObjectURL'. And the url looks like 'blob:[http://127.0.0.1:8080/52090eca-64a0-4262-aeda-34f9c62257b1'](http://127.0.0.1:8080/52090eca-64a0-4262-aeda-34f9c62257b1%27). However, if I put this url to the src in audio tag, this shows nothing.

```
const file = event.detail.text[0].files[0]
urlObj = URL.createObjectURL(file)

<audio src={previewUrlObj} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTMLAudioElement class contains .play() function to open the sound, you need to call it
example:

```
const audioTag = document.createElement("audio");
audioTag.src = "URL";
audioTag.play();
```